# Trying to read in a file using bottle framework

Tags: python, html, frameworks, bottle

I'm trying to read in a file using the bottle framework.

Code:

```
@app.route('/test/upload')
def upload():
    return template('upload')

@app.route('/test/upload', method='POST')
def upload():
    url = request.forms.get('url')
    filename = request.files.get('filename')

    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename.raw_filename)
    print(name)
    ....

    return template('veredict', v = veredict)

app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

And the part of my HTML code that handles the upload:

```
<form action="/test/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-filename">
    <div class="form-group">

      <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" id="url" placeholder="Enter URL" name="url">
    
      <h6>Or submit a file containing URLs:</h6>
      <input type="file" name="filename">
      <div class = "mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

When i run my program I get the following error:

File "fileup.py", line 45, in upload
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename.raw_filename)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raw_filename'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2020 11:13:28] "POST /test/upload HTTP/1.1" 500 1417

I realize my error has something to do with how I'm reading in the file (the variable "filename" is empty, I'm just not sure how to go about fixing it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As far as I can see, this error shouldn't happen.  Are you sure that's the form being submitted, and not some other form?

Comment: @JohnGordon yeah I'm pretty sure. The program works when I read in plain text (such as a url) but for some reason it won't correctly handle a file type input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the form attribute from enctype="multipart/form-filename"  to enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Good catch!  I saw `multipart/blahblah` and didn't look any further.